# Settings button become disabled after updating the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

Take a look at the settings button:
[image]

It is working properly, but after updating the page in WordPress, the settings button becomes Not clickable. Is this caused by js and some jQuery functions?

Here's the js code:

```
if(action === 'blog'){
            var parentDiv   = jQuery(this).parents('.dx-columns');

            // Show hidden divs inside blog dialog
            jQuery('#dx-blog-dialog').find('div').css('display', 'block');

            if(parentDiv.find('.hidden').length){
                jQuery('#dx_blog_posts_num').val(parentDiv.find('.hidden').html());

                var images     = parentDiv.attr('data-blog-image');
                var excerpts   = parentDiv.attr('data-blog-excerpt');

                if(images=='true')
                {
                    jQuery('#dx_blog_featured_image').attr('checked', true);
                }
                if(excerpts=='true')
                {
                    jQuery('#dx_blog_excerpt').attr('checked', true);
                }
            }

            jQuery('#dx-blog-dialog').dialog({
                  width: 500,
                  height: 230,
                  close: function( event, ui ) {
                      jQuery( this ).dialog( "destroy" );

                      // Make divs inside blog dialog hidden
                      jQuery('#dx-blog-dialog').find('div').css('display', 'none');
                  },
                  buttons: {
                    'Save': function () {

                        var num        = $(document).find('#dx_blog_posts_num').val();
                        var image      = $(document).find('#dx_blog_featured_image').is(':checked');
                        var excerpt    = $(document).find('#dx_blog_excerpt').is(':checked');

                        parentDiv.attr('data-blog-image', image);
                        parentDiv.attr('data-blog-excerpt', excerpt);

                        avoidXSSNum = num.replace("script", "");
                        var check   = parentDiv.find('.hidden').length;

                        if(!check) {
                            parentDiv.append('<div class="hidden">' + avoidXSSNum + '</div>');
                        }
                        else{
                            parentDiv.find('.hidden').html(avoidXSSNum);
                        }

                        jQuery(this).dialog('destroy');

                        // Make divs inside blog dialog hidden
                        jQuery('#dx-blog-dialog').find('div').css('display', 'none');
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Or is it some WordPress bug? I'm not sure what is happening. Any help will be appreciated?. HTML for the button:

```
<i class="fa fa-cog pull-right dx-setting-column js-setting-column" title="Element Setting"></i>
```

Comment: This is very interesting question, Can you please explain in detail.

Comment: The button is working unless i update the page in WordPress

Comment: Can you provide link to that page?

Comment: Is the button in the admin or on the public site? Is it a custom setting page?

Comment: The page is not deployed.Yes it is public. I think the problem is somewhere in the javascript

Comment: Show us the HTML for it as well. It's hard to see what's going on if we don't know what the JS is referring to.

Comment: Done, i've pasted the HTML

Comment: Is that really the HTML for the image you have in your post? It doesn't seem to be nearly enough elements.

Comment: Yes but the problem is not with the image, but with the settings icon

Comment: What I mean is that we need to see the HTML for the button. You have a bunch of JS that doesn't tell us anything, since we have _no idea_ what ID refers to what element etc.

Comment: Ok, edited again